# Importing several txt files from certain folder

Tags: r

My goal is to import all txt files from a certain folder into a list.

So I do:

```
setwd(".../folder")
data <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")
lis <- lapply(data, read.csv)
```

However, I would like to avoid using `setwd()`. So I can do:

```
data <- list.files(path = ".../folder", pattern = "\\.txt$")
```

But then of course I get an error message *No such file or directory* as `read.csv` looks in the wrong directory. How can I specify the folder in combination with importing all files in `data`?

Comment: Why are you using `read.csv` for .txt files?

Comment: @AdamQuek why not?

Comment: Doesn't sound like normal practice.

Comment: @AdamQuek OK, I think I can live with that.

Comment: @AdamQuek we don't always have the luxury of having perfect files with perfect filenames, maybe it is just a text file with commas that we received from someone else.

Comment: @zx8754 I understand. Just wondering out loud for potential errors given that we have no idea what the data are...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `full.names` statement in the `list.files`.

```
data <- list.files("../folder", pattern = "\\.txt",full.names = TRUE)
```